# ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T> vs new T()

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, maui

I read through the [Microsoft Maui training](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/store-local-data/4-exercise-store-data-locally-with-sqlite) and came across this part of the sourcecode

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });

    // Add this code
    string dbPath = FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath("people.db3");
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<PersonRepository>(
        s => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<PersonRepository>(s, dbPath));

    return builder.Build();
}
```

I wondered what is the benefit of using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` instead of just using `new`.

Option1

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PersonRepository>(
    s => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<PersonRepository>(s, dbPath));
```

Option2

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PersonRepository>(
    new PersonRepository(dbPath));
```

When testing with both, I couldn't find a difference.
What is the difference between both options?

Comment: No benefit in this case, I guess. Using reflection to create instances makes sense when you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: The difference start to show when `PersonRepository` gets other dependencies that can be resolved from the container. `ActivatorUtilities` calls back into the container to get any dependencies that you didn't specify. In other words, it makes your code less verbose and less likely to change. In your case, however, you should certainly go with the `new` statement. That's much simpler to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The ActivatorUtilities class is used for helper code for various activator services. Use it when some services are inconvenient for dependency injection.The New keyword is used to create objects and call constructors. is the most common way to instantiate a class.